# How to convert my curl to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, url, curl

I am working on Objective-C language and I need to fire curl from Objective-C.

My curl is:

```
curl https://api.start.payfort.com/tokens/ \
    -u test_open_k_91ffe6d8f9efe14fcc91: \
    -d "number=4242424242424242" \
    -d "exp_month=11" \
    -d "exp_year=2016" \
    -d "cvc=123" \
    -d "name=sapana"
```

Please help me how to convert this url in Objective-C and fire url.

I tried some other way but they return response like:

```
{
    error =     {
        code = "not_found";
        extras =         {
            "request_id" = "f8e70bf6-9391-49b0-9403-06cc9485c021";
            time = "2016-01-27T11:10:31Z";
        };
        message = "Not Found";
        type = processing;
    };
}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also, please edit your expectations alongside that process. **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Look at the documentation of `NSURLRequest` and related. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me. But swift

```
func cardSendToPayFort(number:String, exp_month:String, exp_year:String, cvc:String, name:String, completion: ((success: Bool, json: NSDictionary?) -> Void))
{

   let username = "test_open_k_91ffe6d8f9efe14fcc91"
   let password = ""
   let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
   let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
   let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

   let orderURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.start.payfort.com/tokens/")
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: orderURL!)

   request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

   let postString = "number=\(number)&exp_month=\(exp_month)&exp_year=\(exp_year)&cvc=\(cvc)&name=\(name)"
   //let postString = "number=4242424242424242&exp_month=11&exp_year=2016&cvc=123&name=sapana"

   request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

   let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

       if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 201 {
           print("statusCode should be 201, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
           print("response = \(response)")

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
               completion(success: false, json: nil)
           }

       } else {
           let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

           let jsonData = responseString?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
           let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                completion(success: true, json: json)
           }
       }

   }
   task.resume()
 }
```